# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in HTTP GET request

Tags: json, get, observable, angular5

I've created RoleService that sends HTTP get request to get roles data. But it give me error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. undefined 'map' is second one which give that error.

```
@Injectable()
export class RoleService {
  apiRoot: string = 'https://irca1b213eeb.hana.ondemand.com/FIGC/odata.xsodata/role';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getRoles(): Observable<RolesItem[]> {
    let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?$format=json`;
    return this.http.get(apiURL)
        .map(res => {
          console.log(res.json())
          return res.json().results.map(item => {
            console.log(item);
            return new RolesItem(
                item.ROLE_ID,
                item.CLUBS_ID,
                item.ROLE,
                item.DESCRIPTION              
            );
          });
        });
  }

}
```

Created below function on ngOnInit

```
 ngOnInit() {
  //  this.searchField = new FormControl();
    this.results = this.roleService.getRoles()
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You are printing out `res.json()` which clearly show that it doesn't have a `results` property but only a `d` property. Have you tried `d.results`?

Comment: have you imported `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: @Daniel B it has results inside d property.

Comment: Yes, so why are you trying to retrieve it directly like `res.json().results.map` instead of `res.json().d.results.map`?

Comment: @DanielB Thanks. Worked